# javascript hiding eval

Tags: javascript, php, eval

I have a method I'm testing right now for hiding javascript so that the user can't go around searching for it in the source files.

The method is this:

1. You have a bunch of javascript files included to make your application work. Libraries like jQuery, dojo, and your own code. This is pretty standard.
2. There is one critical piece of javascript code without which the app will not function, nor will any curious user be able to make heads or tails of the app without it. This critical piece does not get loaded by script tags. Instead, a small unobtrusive script calls to a database and returns the javascript in a big long string.
3. This string gets eval()-ed to make it live code. But the code was dynamically generated, so it won't show up if the user is looking through the source code or saves the website. Furthermore, you can add some kind of a salt or time-stamp to prevent users from trying to trick the database into revealing your javascript kernel.

I'm trying to get feedback on this from the community, and most of the examples I've turned up for hiding javascript with server-side code has just been people wanting to to include a .php file in the  tags instead of .js. This is totally different.

So there you have it. Is this a good idea? What are the weaknesses?

Comment: `eval` is evil, at least in most of the cases. Also happy debugging with that code obfuscation. It will be PITA and in the end you will notice that there still will be ways to break the code free. I just have to watch my XHRs, copy what I get, put it into any IDE and run a tool that formats the code in a proper way.

Comment: eval is evil  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx

Comment: If the web browser can download it, anyone can view it (eg firebug net tab)

Comment: And why are you hiding scripts from your users? It's worth pointing out that, if you don't want them to see it, you probably shouldn't be sending it to their browser, where the user is in almost complete control of everything (and rightly-so).

Comment: Opera's Dragonfly lets you select `eval`ed strings in the `script` select as well (amongst inline event handlers etc.). There is really no difference to including it directly with a `<script>` tag

Comment: Seems like Dragonfly ends the debate. There are lots of philosophical positions on eval() and whether or not you should hide code, but the fact the even eval-ed code is visible with Opera. Settles it. No, this technique will not hold water.

Answer (score 3):

`eval()` is generally frowned upon, but regardless, the big weakness is that I can simply sniff the HTTP requests and get your script. Obfuscation can make this more inconvenient, but with a good debugger its not that hard to follow a stack trace and get a good idea of what is occurring.

Even if the resource is transferred over SSL, it can be perused/manipulated once it has been loaded by the browser. To test this, I went to a secure website and examined a raw TCP response (both synchronous and asynchronous using XML HTTP) using [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html). As expected, it's encrypted and unreadable. However, the same requests are all visible as plain text in Chrome's network activity inspector.

Comment: Not so (even though this answer got accepted elsewhere) do some more reading.

Answer (score 2):

It's trivial to make Javascript code unreadable by humans (and even highly resistant to reverse engineering) - and you don't need to hide it in a of of other code. But why? Generically, the name given to this kind of code is malware.